# Are github.com repository urls pointing to a folder or a file?

Tags: file, github, directory

is this URL pointing to a .git file, or is it a folder path?  In other words, is /redditclone.git a folder path or a file? The .git portion is throwing me off.

https://github.com/salvatoreallegra/**redditclone.git**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `.git` is optional and still reference to a folder on GitHub side (it will be just `redditclone` if cloned on your side)

On GitHub side, those repositories are bare repos (meaning without working tree, just the Git data content), and by convention, a bare repo is designated by a `.git` extension (even thoug it is a folder)

Comment: Thank you sir.  This helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a folder, the same way as explained on setting up the server:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

```
$ cd /srv/git
$ mkdir project.git
```

this is standard made since the "long ago" times when there were many version control systems used at the same time by the companies and this suffix was meant to distinguish one from another. GitHub decided to adopt that.